# Split a TIFF File

Tags: c#, libtiff, libtiff.net

I need to split TIFF file to many files (each page in a separate file).

I wrote a function but splitting of a large amount of files takes time :/

Then I was searching for a library to do the split and I found the LibTiff.Net but I can't find the split function!!

Can you please help me to use this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the documentation on their website? I found [this](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/extract-a-page-from-a-multi-page-tiff-image.aspx) in about 45 seconds of searching.

If you've tried that, and it doesn't work, update your question.

If you have a budget for this project, I strongly recommend [LEADtools](http://www.leadtools.com/) for all of your TIFF-related image processing needs. I've used it in the past and it's fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

I found this

http://www.sherrodcomputers.com/products_tiffsplitter_dll_download.cfm

does what you need. Simple and faster. Its not free but worth the money (less than 100$ one developer license).